# Mysql inner join on 2 tables don't work

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I have a table in my database named contacts and a table named views.

On the table contacts I have the following fields:

- id
- status
- first_name
- last_name

The status can be cold, prospect or lost.

On the table views I have the following fields:

- user_id
- art_views
- art_title

The relation between those 2 tables is id and user_id.

I need a query to make a new html table with the following columns:

- art_title
- cold
- prospect
- lost

Now I have the following query (UPDATED):

```
SELECT
v.art_title,
SUM(CASE c.status WHEN 'cold' THEN v.art_views ELSE 0 END) cold,
SUM(CASE c.status WHEN 'prospect' THEN v.art_views ELSE 0 END) prospect,
SUM(CASE c.status WHEN 'lost' THEN v.art_views ELSE 0 END) lost
FROM views v
JOIN contacts c ON v.user_id = c.id
GROUP BY v.art_title
```

This query is working now (thanks to Gerv) but i still have users who don't have a status. So i leave the field user_id in the table 'views' empty. How can i change the query for those users so i can count them also?

I tried to: SUM(CASE v.user_id WHEN ' ' THEN v.art_views ELSE 0 END) test,
but with no result here.

Comment: When grouping by multiple columns you use comma to separate the group clauses, not AND.

Comment: I have updated my query. Thanks for that. But it's still not working.

Comment: Swap your tables around, use a LEFT [OUTER] JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN, and count the thing on the right. Alternatively, use a RIGHT JOIN - but no one ever does.

Comment: As the views need to be summarized that table should be on the left side, editted my answer .....

Comment: It's not the c.status that is NULL but the v.user_id. So that's not working your way. I have the error 'Reference 'no_user' not supported (reference to group function)'. But I want to see only the highest numbers for art_views (limited by 10). I mean here the 10 highest numbers in one of the c.status

Answer (score 1):

You can switch the logic by selecting from the views table and joining de contacts table.
Below query will pivot the status with a CASE clause

```
SELECT
    v.art_title,
    SUM(CASE c.status WHEN 'cold' THEN v.art_views ELSE 0 END) cold,
    SUM(CASE c.status WHEN 'prospect' THEN v.art_views ELSE 0 END) prospect,
    SUM(CASE c.status WHEN 'lost' THEN v.art_views ELSE 0 END) lost,
    SUM(CASE c.status WHEN NULL THEN v.art_views ELSE 0 END) no_user
FROM views v
LEFT JOIN contacts c ON v.user_id = c.id
GROUP BY v.art_title
ORDER BY (cold+lost+prospect+no_user) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: How can i populate the right HTML column with your query here?

Comment: I've aliased the SUM with the status name so you should be able to address that value in PHP with `$row['cold']` etc.

Comment: I will try your query and i will let you know of it's working.

Comment: It's working your way, Gerv. Thank you for sharing with me. But i have still one question. I have some users who don't have a status. So i put no user_id in the table views for them. But they can still have views on an art_title. How can i update the query for them?

Comment: I tried to update the first SUM in the query: SUM(CASE v.user_id WHEN ' ' THEN v.art_views ELSE 0 END) test but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`SELECT art_title, SUM(art_views), status FROM contacts AS c INNER JOIN views AS v ON v.user_id = c.id GROUP BY v.art_title, c.status`

Comment: It's also not working. How can i put the correct data in the right html column? I think i can only have 1 query or can i use mysql_num_rows here to have the right number of views per art_title?

Comment: So this would return a number of rows of the form `title, view_for_status, status`.  You would need to iterate the result set to  populate the columns (storing the intermediate values in a php var).  Alternatives are to use multiple SQL queries or to write a more complex nested query.  If you don't have much data, it's probably easiest to do it on the PHP level.

Comment: Can you make an example, arcyqwerty? I don't understand what you mean here. How can i write more SQL queries and populate the right column of status?