# Merge 2 queries with different WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query:

```
select
*
from 
(
SELECT art_titel as at, COUNT(*) as Number1
FROM artikel_views 
WHERE user_id != ''  
GROUP BY art_titel 
ORDER BY Number1 desc
) as FirstSet
join
(
SELECT art_titel as at, COUNT(*) as Number2
FROM artikel_views 
WHERE user_id = ''  
GROUP BY art_titel 
ORDER BY Number2 desc
) as SecondSet
on FirstSet.at = SecondSet.at
```

My HTML table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Art Titel</td>
    <td>user_id is NULL</td>
    <td>user_id is not NULL</td>
  </tr>

<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) { ?>

  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['at']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Number2']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Number1']; ?></td>
  </tr>

<?php } ?>

</table>
```

What i do is taking the values from $row['Number1'] and $row['Number 2'] in combination with the art_titel.
The result from this query is not good. I have only the art_titel and art_views from the matches on art_titel in both queries but it's not good. I want all items in both ways.

I have tried also a UNION but is isn't working my way.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: It's hard to tell without any sample data or expected results (which I recommend you include next time you ask a question. You could edit this one if you're ambitious) but you could try a UNION and see if that works.

Comment: I have tried a UNION a couple of seconds ago and it's also not working my way.

Comment: Those echo need to be put in a WHILE loop,so I guess the number1 and number2 for the last groups happen to be the same,so that`s why you get the same values.

Comment: Show a screen of the results.

Comment: I have updated my question again. I had used a while but was forgot to copy it in my question.

Comment: How can i show you a screen of the results?

Comment: I think you also need to echo the table otherwise you`ll have the same columns overwritten for each iteration.http://stackoverflow.com/a/17902527/1745672

Comment: I do the same thing with my loop of your example. I don't see a problem with my loop.

Comment: I have updated my HTML table so you can better see what i mean, see the headers of the table. Now i have in user_id is NULL and in the user_id is not NULL the same results with your query but it's not correct.

Comment: Try now it was my mistake

Comment: I think it's working now with the right values but the sort is not correct. The ORDER BY Number1 desc and Number2 desc is not working.

Comment: I see the problem here. It's sorting on Number1 first, then Number2. So it's good and works correct.

Comment: @ Mihai: Can you please take a look at this question also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26615254/mysql-inner-join-on-2-tables-dont-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for 2 queries,just use a CASE condition.

```
SELECT art_titel as at, SUM(CASE WHEN user_id != '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Number1,
SUM(CASE WHEN user_id = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Number2
FROM artikel_views 
GROUP BY art_titel 
ORDER BY Number1 desc,Number2 desc
```

Comment: If i use $row['Number1'] and $row['Number2'] are the values the same in combination with art_titel and the values are not the same in my database. So what is going wrong?

Comment: @ Mihai: I want to populate my HTML table with the output of the query. For that i use $row['at'] for the values art_titel and $row[Number1'] for the values in the first column of my table and $row['Number2'] for the values in the second column of my table. The values from Number 1 and Number2 are the same in my table now. But in my database it's not.

Comment: @Mihai: The COUNT count aggregate is incremented for all non-NULL values, so `Number1` and `Number2` are going to the same. Either replace the `ELSE 0` with `ELSE NULL`, or use `SUM` aggregate instead of `COUNT`.

Comment: @spencer7593 http://gp1.wac.edgecastcdn.net/802892/production_public/Artist/3621518/image/small/1378902809_545016088873462_1511234723_o.jpg Thanks.